# Would the startup code still be accessible after an address remap on an RZ/A1L in boot mode 0?

Tags: memory, linker, arm, startup, boot

According to the ["Address Remapping" section of the "*RZ/A1L Group, RZ/A1LU Group, RZ/A1LC Group manual*",](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Renesas/RZ,A1L_LU_LC_Hrdw_Man.pdf#page=100) a remap operation on this MCU causes the address range 0x20000000 - 0x204FFFFF to be allocated to 0x00000000 - 0x004FFFFF. The manual also states in section 3.5.1 that, in boot mode 0, "program execution is started from H'0000_0000". Thus, in boot mode 0, the reset/boot vector must be placed at 0x00000000.

So, if the MCU is booted in boot mode 0 and an address remap is issued shortly after during startup, would the startup code (and reset handler) be accessible after the remap? (Assuming it's linked/downloaded to the start of the CS0 space) Put in another way, would the startup code still run in between 0x00000000 and 0x004FFFFF? Or would it rather run in the CS0 mirror space (0x40000000 - 0x43FFFFFF)?

I was under the understanding that, after the remap, accesses to the 0x00000000 - 0x004FFFFF range would be interpreted by the MMU as accesses to the range 0x20000000 - 0x204FFFFF, which is ultimately why it is advantageous for the vector table to be remapped.

Comment: this is hardly an MCU.  When you read the arm documentation you see that the arm can use 0x00000000 or 0xFFFF0000 for the exception vectors which is reflected in this chips documentation and boot modes.  It is a cortex A so it starts by executing at an address not a set of vectors, but you can easily link for any address space you want and have the bootstrap code be position independent.

Comment: the mapping isnt an overwrite there isnt a copy going on not going to read the whole manual for you depending on either how the chip works or how your board or etc works you can build for 0x00000000 and leave it mapped that way forever or you build for the address space where the ram/flash is that you intend to run from and use the boot mode mapping simply to get started.

Comment: @old_timer Thank you for your comments. I've revised the question title and description above in hopes of more accurately/clearly addressing my curiosity.

Comment: while you can use the mmu that is not what they are talking about it is logic that maps that address space, for example if 0x20000000 was mapped to 0x00000000 in this way then you can access either 0x00001234 or 0x20001234 and get the same data in the same memory/device, think in terms of software as if mode = x then if address & mask = y then address =0x20000000 | (address & ~mask).    if address = bob smith then contact 123 main street, if address = 123 main street then contact 123 main street.  in logic

Comment: logic already has to divide up the address space, if upper address bits are x then route the transaction to the sd controller/interface, if the upper address bits are y then route the transaction to the emmc controller if the upper address bits are z then route the transaction to the spi controller, and so onfor internal periperals,  having optional destinations for part of the address space (specifically 0x00000000 where reset handlers happen and customers may wish to choose their non volatile storage solution)

Comment: each chip/vendor does it differently.  depending on the chip and or core if as in this case it has a third party cpu core (from arm) it varies.  this version of arm core should have a VTOR register that can be used to re-map the vector table once up and running, so the strapping options get it started then you can both have the 0x00000000 code branch to the real address space for that memory/storage option you have chosen then change the vector table to point at it then

Comment: 0x00000000 can be remaped for other purposes as needed/desired per the chip options and your coding choices.  but again depends on chip and its options.  And this is not an MCU in any sense of the term as the sections you have shown outline, (off chip storage for this NV boot media, off chip storage for that NV boot media, etc).

Comment: @old_timer Ah, I understand now. Again, thank you very much for your comments! I'll see if I can take your comments here and consolidate them into an answer to address my curiosities and misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @old_timer's comments, I was able to identify a misunderstanding on my part with respect to the concept of memory mapping. After "connecting the dots" and resolving this misunderstanding, it gave way to the answer to this question.

What I was (embarrassingly) not understanding before was that the whole purpose of a remap operation is to reconfigure a set of addresses that are associated with a specific memory device/interface (e.g. SPI, flash, SRAM, etc.) with a different one.

With this in mind, at bootup (and before a remap operation), the CS0 space is mapped to a specific device: SRAM with byte selection or burst ROM (asynchronous or
synchronous), as specified on [page 181 of the User Manual](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Renesas/RZ,A1L_LU_LC_Hrdw_Man.pdf#page=181)). In boot mode 0, the startup code would subsequently need to be loaded into that same device, whatever it may be (either SRAM or burst ROM). In boot mode 1, the startup code would need to reside in the SPI multi-I/O bus space (serial flash memory); in boot mode 2, SD controller (NAND flash memory); etc.

After a remap, the CS0 address space is subsequently mapped to the on-chip RAM. The code that was executing before the remap still resides in and executes from where it was loaded.